# How to make AWS Cognito Guest Access granted via OTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm building a mobile application that has its backend accessed via API Gateway, and secured with Cognito User pools.

The app has a quite long onboarding process, and for business reasons it has to be that way. That onboarding process calls a couple of API endpoints to get certain information and all of that is done before we can create the user, so all of this APIs have to be accessed by a "guest user".

Is there a way to protect that APIS with a token generated with an OTP (link) sent via Email or SMS?

PD: I have clear that is necessary to make a custom authenticator.

I have read most of cognito documentation and I only see this kind of custom authentication flow (magic link) but it's related to existing user.

> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/implementing-passwordless-email-authentication-with-amazon-cognito/

The final result that I want to achieve is to allow only OTP verified users to use the onboarding API's, maybe via a temporary access_token configured via the OTP link?

Example flow:
[app flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq1Qk.png)